# Difference between unsigned and std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, fpga

can anyone tell me about the difference between below written statement.

```
signal A: **unsigned**(3 downto 0);
signal B: **std_logic_vector**(3 downto 0);
```

Comment: may be [this](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/std_logic_vector-vs-unsigned-vs-signed.21345/) help you

Comment: *A type is characterized by a set of values and a set of operations* (1076-2008 5.1 Types). *The types created by the elaboration of distinct type definitions are distinct types* (6.2 Type declarations). Some operations for the base types of the subtype std_logic_vector are found in package std_logic_vector_1164, for subtypes signed and unsigned in package numeric_std. The latter package provides binary math operations. Package numeric_std_unsigned provides the same unsigned operations for std_logic_vector. The base types are closely related and eligible for type conversion (9.3.6).

Comment: as the name says: `std_logic_vector` is just a vector (aka array) of `std_logic` elements. And `std_logic` is the resolved version of `std_ulogic`. And so on. The rest is explained in the comment by user1155120: no mathematical operators are defined in the `std_logic_1164`. For `unsigned` and `signed`, their mathematical operations are defined in the same package they are (`numeric_std`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both `std_logic_vector` and `unsigned` are *unconstrained arrays* of `std_logic`. As is the `signed` type. `std_logic_vector` is declared in the `std_logic_1164` package; `unsigned` and `signed` are declared in the package `numeric_std`. All three types are identical; the only difference is their names.

So, what's the point of that? The point is well illustrated by an example:

With

```
variable U : unsigned(3 downto 0);
variable S : signed(3 downto 0);
variable I : integer;
```

then

```
U := "1111";
I := to_integer(U);
```

results in `I` being given the value 15, whereas

```
S := "1111";
I := to_integer(S);
```

results in `I` being given the value -1. This is because the `unsigned` type is used to represent an *unsigned* number, which can only be positive. So, `"1111"` represents the number 15. A `signed` type, however, needs to be able to represent negative numbers, too, and with the `signed` type `"1111"` represents -1 (because the *twos complement* representation is used by this type).

So, you can see that the same function - `to_integer` - returns two different results when called with `"1111"` - either 15 or -1 depending on whether the argument is of type `unsigned` or `signed`. So, you can see the point in having both types, even though the only difference between them is their name.

Actually, there are two `to_integer` functions, not one. One takes an `unsigned` argument; the other (identically named `to_integer`) takes a `signed` argument. As you can see, they do behave differently. The compiler can decide which function needs to be called based on the type of the argument. This idea, where a compiler can choose between different (but identically-named functions) based on the type of the argument, is called *overloading*. It is common in software languages.

So, what about `std_logic_vector`? Suppose you wrote:

```
variable V : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
variable I : integer;
```

then

```
V:= "1111";
I := to_integer(V);
```

what result would you expect from the `to_integer` function? 15 or -1? This dilemma is solved by the above code being illegal - it won't compile. It won't compile, because there is no version of the `to_integer` function defined for `std_logic_vector` - the `to_integer` function is not overloaded for the type `std_logic_vector`.

So, if you only need to represent positive numbers, you're best off using the `unsigned` type; if you need to represent negative numbers you need to use the `signed` type. If you don't really care, because your pattern of bits is not a number or because your not doing any maths on it (you're merely transporting it from one place to another), then you're best off using `std_logic_vector`.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Qq4